# PNG Texture File from Blender instead of a mtl file

Tags: export, blender, render-to-texture, arcore

I was trying out ARCore by Google. But I'm not able to export my 3D Model in Blender to a obj and png combination instead of the default obj and mtl combination. I'm kinda new to Blender. I also tried [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90301/export-obj-file-with-png-texture/90302#90302?newreg=fba36f12e56a4615afc088293b187cc6) from Stack Exchange but with no avail.

Comment: Did you try dragging the PNG alone into the project pane? That will create a material in the Materials folder. You can add that material to the OBJ (that's been dragged into the project tab)

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Regis_AG Nope I didn't, I went the unity way which had much much better support for modeling in 3D and AR.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to user the ARCore this maybe be a solution if your focus is Sceneform.

After export the .obj and .mtl create a folder in Android using the Sample Data Directory (to avoid this making part of your project)

[image]

Inside this folder add the .obj and .mtl

Go to Android **Preferences** > **Plugins** and search for "Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)"

[image]

Clicking with the right button on the .obj you can select "Import Sceneform Asset"
This will create the .sfb and .sfa file, already ready to use.

And in your **App Gradle** you should find new lines like this:

```
sceneform.asset('sampledata/NAME_OF_FILE.obj',
    'default',
    'sampledata/NAME_OF_FILE.sfa',
    'src/main/assets/NAME_OF_FILEl')
```